# How can I iterate through an array of objects, make an API call for each object, then set the response as a value in each object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array of objects (mergedArray) that I need to iterate through, call an api for each object, then set that response as a new value. Every time I do this the array gets returned with `industry: Promise { <pending> }`

```
let responseArray = await Promise.all( mergedArray.map(i =>{
  return (
    {...i, industry: atomTest()}
  )
}))
console.log(responseArray)
```

Using this function to fetch the data..

```
const atomTest = async () => {

  await fetch('https://*********', 
  {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {accept: 'application/json', 'content-type': 'application/json'},
    body: JSON.stringify({
      asset: {identifier: 'ticker', value: 'NKE', assetType: 'equity', market: 'USA'}
    })
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then((response )=> {
    console.log(response.lists[0].name)
    return(response.lists[0].name)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
}
```

Replacing 'atomTest()' with a function that just returns a string gives the correct result, how would I do this with an async function? I can't seem to figure out how to let the function wait for the fetch result before moving on.

Any help would be massively appreciated :)

Comment: If you are in charge of the API, I would highly suggest to refactor it to accept and array of objects instead of needing to call the API on every single one to reduce network traffic, and increasing the overall speed of API call. You can then easily return the needed data, and iterate through it.

Comment: Things would be very different if I had control of the API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `await` for the API call to complete in the `map` callback:

```js
async function callAPI(n) {
    return fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/' + n)
        .then(response => response.json())
}

mergedArray = [1, 2, 3]

async function main() {
    let responseArray = await Promise.all(mergedArray.map(async i => {
        return {i, industry: await callAPI(i)}
    }))

    console.log(responseArray)
}

main()
```

Comment: Thank you king!!! Got it working using this . beast mode ...